# how to get a number from a string using only std::string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

i have a function that accepts two strings , "first" and "second"
i want to check if the second string is in this format :
"first"_number , so i can retuurn the number in the second string

for example if the first string is hello
and the second string is hello_7 , then i want to return 7 .. 
if the string is not in this format i return 0 ..

any help ? i can only use string std .. if htere is no other way then i can use other std functions.

```
int Plain::getNumber(string first, string second){
    std::size_t pos = second.find("_");
    std::string str1 = str.substr (0,pos);
    if(str1  ==  first){
    // here i want to get the number
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I rarely advocate [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) but this might be a case where it might be useful. Especially if the number can be any arbitrary number, and not just a single digit. C++ have some [nice regex functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) that can be used to copy substrings. It's trivial to use the first string to construct the regex to match the second string at run-time.

Comment: Can it be any number or ony a digit?

Comment: yes .. i want to get the number after the  "_" , if there is no number then i think i will return 0 from the function

Comment: @kasandra Shouldn't the condition `if(str1  !=  first){` to enter `// here i want to get the number`?

Comment: mm no because i want the first half of the string to be equal to first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating your code to check for bad input...

```
int Plain::getNumber(string first, string second){   //"hello" and "hello_7"

    string matchPattern = first + "_";     // "hello_"

    std::size_t pos = second.find(matchPattern); // find "hello_" within "hello_7"
    if (pos != 0) {   // validate that it's at the beginning
        return 0;     // not a match
    }

    string postFix = second.substr(matchPattern.size());

    return (int)strtol(postFix.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) can throw exceptions.

Comment: I started to use `strtol(postFix.c_str(), NULL, 10);` instead, but though the std::stoi approach was more "c++" like since folks have a tendency to downvote when they see "c" code.

Comment: I saw that, and was about to write a note about [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) will not return `0` if the number in the string will over- or under-flow. Either solution is good, you just need to add some extra error-handling. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using C++11 you can use std::stoi

`std::string someString = "23123";
int parsedNumber = std::stoi(someString);`

otherwise, use atoi:
`std::string someString = "23123";
int parsedNumber = atoi(someString.c_str());`

Comment: i am using C++0x .. i am gonna try this

Comment: Never use atoi in C++ or C - it cannot detect errors. If you can't use C++11, there are several far better alternatives, such as sscanf or strtol or using an input stream.

Comment: i want to use strtol but i am scared of it , because i am not sure if i can use it

Comment: Why be scared? It cannot format your C drive if you end up misusing it once.